# Integral over the full support of a square and cube of a convolution of normal and uniform

Tags: integration, probability-theory, normal-distribution

I've got a uniform random variable $X\sim\mathcal{U}(-a,a)$ and a normal random variable $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$.  I am interested in their sum $Z=X+Y$.  Using the convolution integral, one can derive the p.d.f. for $Z$:

$$f_Z(x)=\frac{1}{2a\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{x-a}^{x+a}e^{-\frac{u^2}{2\sigma^2}}du=\frac{1}{2a}\left[\Phi\left(\frac{x+a}{\sigma}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{x-a}{\sigma}\right)\right]$$
where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the normalized Gaussian cdf.

I am trying to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_Z^2(x)dx$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_Z^3(x)dx$.  Are there bounds on these expressions in terms of elementary functions?  Can they be expressed in terms of a finite sum involving $\Phi(\cdot)$?

Comment: Upper bound? Lower bound? What are you looking for? Note that by the mean-value theorem, you have that $\Phi((x+a)/\sigma) - \Phi((x-a)/\sigma) = \varphi(\xi)(2 a /\sigma)$ for some $\xi \in [(x-a)/\sigma,(x+a)/\sigma]$ where $\varphi = \Phi'$. Now $\varphi'$ doesn't change sign too many times, so you can use one endpoint or the other (in the appropriate places) to get a bound.

Comment: I'm interested in both upper and lower bounds. Good idea on the MVT, will try that, though I think earlier I tried it on a similar problem and didn't get a tight enough bound. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can get lower bounds by using Renyi entropy as follows. Let $h(f) = - \mathbb E( \log f(X) )$ be the differential entropy. Then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f^{\alpha+1}(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = \mathbb E f^\alpha(X)$. By Jensen's inequality, $\log( \mathbb E f^\alpha(X) ) \geq \alpha \mathbb E \log f(X) = - \alpha h(f)$. So $\mathbb E f^{\alpha}(X) \geq \exp(-\alpha h(f))$. I gave you some tight bounds on the Shannon entropy for this problem in a comment to another question of yours.

Comment: That's very neat (and works in other cases where you have a tight bound on the entropy of an otherwise painful distribution)!  Thanks!

Comment: Note that I use the natural log throughout (including in my definition of differential entropy) and not $\log_2$. But, you can adjust that easily, if needed. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like $$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_Z(x)^2\ dx = -{\frac {{\sigma}}{2{a}^{2}\sqrt {\pi }}}+\frac{1}{2a}
{{\rm erf}\left({\frac {a}{{\sigma}}}\right)}+ \frac{\sigma}{2a^2 \sqrt{\pi}}  {{\rm e}^{-a^2/\sigma^2}} 
$$

EDIT: OK, here's the proof.

For convenience, scale distances so that $\sigma = 1$.  We're looking at

$$J =\frac{1}{8 \pi a^2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx  \int_{x-a}^{x+a} ds \int_{x-a}^{x+a} dt\ e^{-(s^2+t^2)/2} $$

Interchange the order of integration so this becomes

$$\eqalign{ J &=  \frac{1}{8 \pi a^2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty ds \int_{s-2a}^{s+2a} dt \int_{\max(s,t)-a}^{\min(s,t)+a} dx\ e^{-(s^2+t^2)/2}\cr
&=   \frac{1}{8 \pi a^2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty ds \int_{s-2a}^{s+2a} dt\ (2a + \min(s,t) -\max(s,t)) e^{-(s^2+t^2)/2} \cr}$$

Break this up into two pieces, one where $s<t$ and the other where $s>t$.

$$ \eqalign{J_1 &= \frac{1}{8 \pi a^2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty ds \int_s^{s+2a} dt\ (2a + s-t) e^{-(s^2+t^2)/2}\cr
J_2 &=  \frac{1}{8 \pi a^2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty ds \int_{s-2a}^{s} dt\ (2a + t-s) e^{-(s^2+t^2)/2}\cr}$$

In $J_1$, take $t = s+u$ (so that $-(s^2+t^2)/2 = -s^2 - us - t^2/2$); in $J_2$, take $t = s - u$ (so that $-(s^2+t^2)/2 = -s^2 +us - t^2/2$).  With these changes of variables we recombine the integrals:

$$ J = \frac{1}{8 \pi a^2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty ds \int_0^{2a} du\ (2a - u) e^{-s^2} (e^{-us} + e^{us}) e^{-u^2/2} $$

Interchange the order of integration again

$$ \eqalign{J &= \frac{1}{8 \pi a^2} \int_0^{2a} du \int_{-\infty}^\infty ds\ (2a-u) e^{-s^2} (e^{-us}+e^{us}) e^{-u^2/2} \cr
  &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi} a^2} \int_0^{2a} du\ (a-u/2) e^{-u^2/4}\cr
  &= \frac{1}{2a} \text{erf}(a) + \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi} a^2} e^{-a^2} - \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi} a^2}\cr}$$

Comment: Any chance you could post how you arrived at that?  Thanks!

Comment: Acgually I got it from Maclaurin series: it seems that the series is $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(4k+2)(k+1)!\sqrt{\pi}} \frac{a^{2k}}{\sigma^{1+2k}}$$
But it should be possible to prove more directly.

Comment: Very nice proof!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a complete answer but just a suggestion for part of your question.

$f_Z$ is the convolution of a uniform density and a Gaussian density.  Thus,
its Fourier transform or characteristic function $\Psi_Z$ is the product of 
a Gaussian function and a sinc function.  Parseval's theorem then gives us
that
$$
\int (f_Z)^2 = \int |\Psi_Z|^2
$$
(there may be a $2\pi$ or something similar that needs to be included in that 
equation depending on how the Fourier transform is defined).
The integrand on the right hand side is the product of *another* Gaussian
and a $\text{sinc}^2$ function, and the integral on the right might even have a 
closed form that is known already, or be more amenable to numerical
integration than something that requires multiple computations of values of 
$\Phi(x)$.